# How to get email confirmation to work on Supabase local development environment

Tags: authentication, sveltekit, supabase, supabase-js

I working on authentication on a Supabase and SvelteKit project. I have setup the authentication client and Signup works fine, but the email confirmation is causing problems. I am running a local development environment using Supabase CLI and Docker Desktop, and the confirmation email is sent to the InBucket link at http://localhost:54324. But When I click on the link I get a 500 internal server error.

I have setup the email is the config.toml file in the Supabase directory.

```
auth.email.template.confirmation]
subject = "Confirm your sign up email"
content_path = "./supabase/templates/confirmSignup.html"

[auth.email.template.magic_link]
subject = "Your magic link"
content_path = "./supabase/templates/magicLink.html"
```

Here is the confirmation link being used in the confirmation template:
http://localhost:5173/auth/confirm?token_hash=TOKEN_HASH_HERE&type=email

I am fairly certain I have done these correctly, and I don't know what I am missing.